# Why does main() require braces?

Tags: c++, language-design, program-entry-point

I tried several variations on

```
main() return;
```

or

```
main() if();
```

and obtained different errors, the most peculiar of which was

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

While it's uncommon for a program to require only one statement, why does main() make it a requirement to have braces?

Could someone explain why the error was so peculiar when compiling just int main();?

Comment: are you trying to say, void OneStatement() printf("One Statement"); would be a valid function definition.

Comment: Your premise is incorrect. Neither `main` nor any other function is required to start with a brace. This is a valid program: `int main() try { throw 1; } catch (...) { return 0; }`. (That's called a *function try block*, and aside from that, *all* functions' bodies must be enclosed it braces, not just `main`'s).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you are defining a function named `main()` and a function definition is basically a function declaration (the `int main()` part) followed by a compound statement (the `{ /* ... */ }` part) (you could also use a function try block, but those are very rarely used and still require braces).

You can't define any function without braces.

Comment: Thanks, I just learnt about try blocks. Not to mention, I put braces into perspective.

Comment: Just a little extra clarification. You can declare a function signature without braces i.e. `void test();` however, you must implement it somewhere later using braces. You will see a lot of code that does this, especially within class definitions to try to hold as true as possible to encapsulation.

Answer (score 8):

It's not unique to main -- the body of any function must be surrounded by braces. Specifically §8.4/1 defines a *function-body* as a "compound-statement" (and, for the truly pedantic, §6.3/1 defines a *compound-statement* as: "{ statement-seq<sub>opt</sub> }".

Answer (score 5):

Because it is a function.  It's part of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Because the C++ standard says that all functions with a body must have braces. That's just the way the standard is defined, for better or for worse.